# Represent code in math notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

x:= 0; y:= 0
 If (q≤ p ∧ p=0){
If ¬ (q=0 ∧ p≤ q) { x := x+q; }
else { y := y+p; } }
else
{ x:= x+1 ; y:= y+1; }

How can I represent the code in math notation?

Here is my attempt at it:

(((q≤ p ∧ p=0)∧(¬ (q=0 ∧ p≤ q)))->x=q) ∧ (((q≤ p ∧ p=0)∧(q=0 ∧ p≤ q))->y=p) ∧ ¬(q≤ p ∧ p=0) -> x=1 ∧ y=1)

Simplify the code by removing any dead code? Not sure

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in math notation:

> Let $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. Assume $q \le 0$. If $q \neq 0$, let $x \mapsto x+q$, otherwise let $y \mapsto y + p$.
>
> Otherwise, let $q = 0$. Then let $x \mapsto x + 1$ and $y \mapsto y+1$.

---

The condition $(q \le p) \wedge p = 0$ can only be true if $q \le 0$. If $p = 0$, then $q \le 0$ means that $q$ must be negative, since $q > 0$ negates $q \le p$.

Incidentally, this is why math notation is words and not symbols. You have superfluous, meaningless conditions given your restrictions.

Comment: sorry we can't assume q<=0. q and p belongs to set of natural numbers. Should have mentioned that!

Comment: @user88282 See my edit.